# Push notifications Service using monotouch

Tags: iphone, xamarin.ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I am  starting to look for the Apple Push Notification Service .
I have an created using Monotouch  framework,

How can I start to let my app use the apple Push Notification Service,

Should I create a Web Service that handle my event and if the insert event is captured for example I send data to the APNS and that is all
or should I create something particular.
and in the Client Side Should I add some method to handle the notification from APNS???
I am really confused and I don't know from where should I start doing all this.
Thanks in Advance for your help

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Trying to figure out the client site of APNS with MonoTouch, i found this article very helpful:
[Push notifications in iOS with MonoTouch](http://roycornelissen.wordpress.com/2011/05/12/push-notifications-in-ios-with-monotouch/)

Answer (score 7):

The two resources I would start with while beginning to learn about APN are below:

[About Local Notifications and Push Notifications](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Introduction/Introduction.html)

[How to build an Apple Push Notification provider server](http://blog.boxedice.com/2009/07/10/how-to-build-an-apple-push-notification-provider-server-tutorial/)

You may also want to check out [Urban Airship](http://urbanairship.com/). They provide a free APN provider for up to 1 million messages a month.

There is also a project on code.google.com specifically using MonoTouch with APN. [apns-sharp](http://code.google.com/p/apns-sharp/downloads/detail?name=MonoTouch-ClientPushNotificationSample.zip&can=2&q=) I haven't looked at the code but I may help you out.

Comment: Thanks I understand the server Side provider, it is easy to implement,
But I have only few questions How can we get the key from the clientDevice using monotouch,
and I think that we have to overide three methods in the client Side:- public override void FailedToRegisterForRemoteNotifications (UIApplication application, NSError error)
- public override void RegisteredForRemoteNotifications (UIApplication application, NSData deviceToken)
- public override void ReceivedRemoteNotification (UIApplication application, NSDictionary userInfo)

Comment: apns-sharp as mentioned by hipplar has a monotouch project that will help you out with registering for remote notifications. See here http://code.google.com/p/apns-sharp/downloads/list

Comment: What about in app purchase ??? Do you have any idea??

Comment: Different question, ask a new question.

Comment: BTW, apns-sharp has moved to github: https://github.com/Redth/APNS-Sharp

Answer (score 4):

Push Sharp might be useful for you 
https://github.com/Redth/PushSharp/

It's like a new version of APNS-Sharp. You'll have to code your iPhone app (so you can be able to recieve APN) and then use Push Sharp for your APNS provider server.